# Knockout - Binding to reference object

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, knockout.js

I have a knockout application where an Estimate is the main object for the page. The estimate contains an observableArray of WorkOrder objects (WorkOrdersDTO), but only one WorkOrder object is shown for editing at a time. The user is able to choose which WorkOrder is shown for editing by choosing from a select list. The problem that I am having is that I am using an object named CurrentWorkOrder to reference the WorkOrder that is currently being edited. I am running into some performance issues when this object is being set. The more WorkOrders that the estimate contains, the worse these performance issues become. The biggest issue arises when the user adds a WorkOrder. This is the code for that process:

```
self.addWorkOrder = function () {
    tempWOId += 1;
    var workOrder = new WorkOrder();
    workOrder.WorkOrderId(tempWOId);
    workOrder.WorkOrderNo(self.SetWorkOrderNo());
    self.estimate().WorkOrdersDTO.push(workOrder);
    self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder($.grep(self.estimate().WorkOrdersDTO(), function (wo) { return wo == workOrder })[0]);
};
```

The final line in that function is the one that takes the most time. I have tried also using this but it is even slower.

```
self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder(self.estimate().WorkOrdersDTO()[self.estimate().WorkOrdersDTO().length - 1]);
```

I have also taken out the 'with' bindings in my html, but have not seen any results from that. I even commented out the entire html where the bindings where taking place to make sure the performance issues were not cause by that and there was no change in performance.

Any ideas?

I went back and timed that line of code with several different ways and here are the results:
CurrentWorkOrder($.grep) - 613.000ms

CurrentWorkOrder(WorkOrdersDTO.length) - 740.000ms

CurrentWorkOrder(workOrder) - 689.000ms

CurrentWorkOrder($.grep) without html referencing - 317.000ms

There is much better performance when the HTML that binds to the CurrentWorkOrder is removed, leading me to believe that is some of the issue. This is the entire HTML of that section:

```
<div id="work-order-details">
        <div class="work-order-details" data-bind='with: estimate' style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:right;">
                                    Group
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="k-input" data-bind='options: WorkOrderGroupsDTO, value: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderGroupId, optionsValue: "WorkOrderGroupId", optionsText: "GroupName", optionsCaption: "--Select--"'></select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="AddWorkOrderGroupButton"><span class="icon-add" data-bind='click: $root.addWorkOrderGroup'></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Service Date
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input style="width:120px;" id='service-date' data-bind="value: CurrentWorkOrder().ServiceDateDisplay" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;">
                        Additional Work Orders&nbsp;<select id='workOrderSelect' class="k-input num-textbox" data-bind="options: WorkOrdersDTO, optionsValue: 'WorkOrderId', optionsText: 'WorkOrderNo'"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="work-order-details" data-bind='with: estimate'>
            <table class="table-container" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;">
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header" colspan="2">INSTRUCTIONS</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <textarea class="textarea" name="" id="estimate-textarea" rows="4" data-bind='value: CurrentWorkOrder().Instructions' placeholder='Enter Instructions...'></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header labor-tasks">LABOR INFORMATION 
                        <a href="#" data-bind='click: $root.addWorkOrderLaborTask'>Add</a>
                    </th>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header packing-materials">PACKING MATERIALS<a href="#" data-bind='click: $root.addWorkOrderPackingMaterial'>Add</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                    <td class="table-cell-3 labor-tasks" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <table class="estimate-table">
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Task</td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td>Hours</td>
                                <td>RT Rate</td>
                                <td>OT Rate</td>
                                <td>PT Rate</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderLaborTasksDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="k-input smaller-textbox" data-bind='options: LaborTaskData, value: LaborTaskId, optionsValue: "LaborTaskId", optionsText: "Task", optionsCaption: "--Select--"'/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="number" min='0' class="k-textbox num-textbox" style="width:40px;" data-bind='value: Quantity' onkeypress="return numeric_only(event)" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="number" min='0' class="k-textbox num-textbox" data-bind='value: TotalHours' onkeypress="return numeric_only(event)" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        $0.00
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        $0.00
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        $0.00
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span data-bind='text: TotalCostDisplay'></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeWorkOrderLaborTask'>X</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-cell-2 packing-materials" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <table class="estimate-table">
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Material</td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td>Unit Price</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderPackingMaterialsDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><select style="width:275px;" class="k-input" data-bind="options: PackingMaterialData, value: MaterialId, optionsValue: 'MaterialId', optionsText: 'Description', optionsCaption: '--Select--'"></select></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" min='0' class="k-textbox num-textbox" data-bind='value: Quantity' onkeypress="return numeric_only(event)" /></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind='text: UnitPrice'></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind='text: CostDisplay'></span></td>
                                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeWorkOrderPackingMaterial'>X</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header installation-products">INSTALLATION <a id='add-installation-product' href="#" data-bind="click: $root.addWorkOrderInstallationProduct">Add</a></th>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header unitized-items">UNITIZED PRICING <a id='add-installation-product' href="#" data-bind="click: $root.addWorkOrderUnitizedItem">Add</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                    <td class="table-cell-2 installation-products" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <table class="estimate-table">
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Manufacturer</td>
                                <td>Product Line</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderInstallationProductsDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td hidden data-bind='text: WorkOrderInstallationProductId'></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="k-input larger-textbox select-mfr" data-bind="options: ManufacturerData, value: ManufacturerId, optionsValue: 'ManufacturerId', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: '--Select--'"></select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select data-bind="options: ProductLines, value: ProductId, optionsValue: 'ProductLineId', optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: '--Select--'" id="" class="k-input big-textbox"></select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-bind="text: CostDisplay"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.editWorkOrderInstallationProduct'>Edit</a>
                                        <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeWorkOrderInstallationProduct'>X</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-cell-2 unitized-items" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <table class="estimate-table">
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Service</td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td>Unit Price</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderUnitizedItemsDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><select style="width:275px;" class="k-input" data-bind="options: UnitizedItemData, value: UnitId, optionsValue: 'UnitId', optionsText: 'Description', optionsCaption: '--Select--'"></select></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" min='0' class="k-textbox num-textbox" data-bind='value: Quantity' style="width:40px;" onkeypress="return numeric_only(event)" /></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind='text: UnitPrice'></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind='text: CostDisplay'></span></td>
                                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeWorkOrderUnitizedItem'>X</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header storage">STORAGE & HANDLING <a id='add-storage' href="#" data-bind="click: $root.addWorkOrderStorage">Add</a></th>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header tech-services">TECH SERVICES<a href="#" data-bind='click: $root.addWorkOrderTechService'>Add</a></th>                    
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                    <td class="table-cell-2 storage" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <table class="estimate-table">
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Inventory</td>
                                <td>Storage</td>
                                <td>Handling</td>
                                <td>Valuation</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderStoragesDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="storage-cell"><span data-bind="text: InventoryTypeName"></span></td>
                                    <td class="storage-cell"><span data-bind="text: EstimatedStorage"></span></td>
                                    <td class="storage-cell"><span data-bind="text: HandlingIn"></span></td>
                                    <td class="storage-cell"><span data-bind='text: ValuationTypeCharges'></span></td>
                                    <td class="storage-cell"><span data-bind='text: EstimatedStorage'></span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-cell-2 tech-services" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                    <table class="estimate-table">
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Service</td>
                                <td>Qty</td>
                                <td>Unit Price</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderTechServicesDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><select style="width:275px;" class="k-input" data-bind="options: TechServiceData, value: UnitId, optionsValue: 'UnitId', optionsText: 'Description', optionsCaption: '--Select--'"></select></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" min='0' class="k-textbox num-textbox" data-bind='value: Quantity' onkeypress="return numeric_only(event)" /></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind='text: UnitPrice'></span></td>
                                    <td><span data-bind='text: CostDisplay'></span></td>
                                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeWorkOrderTechService'>X</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header other-services">OTHER SERVICES <a id='add-other-service' href="#" data-bind='click: $root.addWorkOrderOtherService'>Add</a></th>
                    <th class="table-cell-2 estimate-wo-header third-party-services">THIRD PARTY SERVICES <a id='add-third-service' href="#" data-bind='click: $root.addWorkOrderThirdPartyService'>Add</a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class='table-row'>
                    <td class="table-cell-2 other-services" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <table class='estimate-table'>
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Description</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderOtherServicesDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input style="width:360px;" class="k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value: Description" /></td>
                                    <td><input class="k-textbox smaller-textbox" data-bind='value: CostDisplay' onkeypress="return numeric_only(event)" /></td>
                                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeWorkOrderOtherService'>X</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-cell-2 third-party-services" style="border:solid 1px darkgray;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                        <table class='estimate-table'>
                            <tr class="header-row">
                                <td>Description</td>
                                <td>Source</td>
                                <td>Src Cost</td>
                                <td>Cost</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody class='table-body' data-bind="foreach: CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderThirdPartyServicesDTO">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value: Description" /></td>
                                    <td><input class="k-textbox smaller-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value: Source" /></td>
                                    <td><input class="k-textbox mini-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value: SourceCost" /></td>
                                    <td><input class="k-textbox mini-textbox" data-bind='value: CostDisplay' style="width:40px;" /></td>
                                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeWorkOrderThirdPartyService'>X</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I was thinking that not using tables could make the markup render faster, but I have been hesitant to switch it because that is what the other developers are more comfortable with.

Comment: What does the html for your `<select>` look like? Since you already have the "current" workorder when adding, why not `self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder(workOrder)`

Comment: I would start by working out what bindings use the CurrentWorkOrder observable ( getSubscriptionsCount might help here ).  Also, if you are using KO 2.x ALL bindings on an element fire if any binding updated.  This can have some interesting performance when Select element using option bindings.  Consider upgrading to ko 3.0.  Otherwise you'll need to put breakpoints in the KO libraries to looks at the observable/dependantObservables firing in the chain ( functions evaluateImmediately - readFunction.call line is a good start ).

Comment: @RobertSlaney When I use getSubscriptionsCount on the CurrentWorkOrder, it says there are 17.

Comment: @Origineil This is the HTML for my select `<select id='workOrderSelect' class="k-input num-textbox" data-bind="options: WorkOrdersDTO, optionsValue: 'WorkOrderId', optionsText: 'WorkOrderNo'"></select>`. Also, I had set the CurrentWorkOrder to workOrder and it was slightly slower than $.grep. 689ms vs 613ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to substantially speed up the process with some small changes to the addWorkOrder function.

```
self.addWorkOrder = function () {
    tempWOId += 1;
    self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder(new WorkOrder());
    self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderId(tempWOId);
    self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder().WorkOrderNo(self.SetWorkOrderNo());
    self.estimate().WorkOrdersDTO.push(self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder());
};
```

Rather than instantiating the workOrder into it's own variable each time, I am just setting the CurrentWorkOrder to a new WorkOrder and setting its properties directly. This has made it about 8x faster, which should be acceptable.

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: Look in your HTML posted above and count the number of times the CurrentWorkOrder appears in ANY binding.  That binding will execute if the value of CurrentWorkOrder changes (select for WorkOrderGroupsDTO,   8 foreach bindings on tbody tags). They all have to be re-rendered and it all adds up. Try to think of your observables and a great big tree.  At the top is CurrentWorkOrder. You have 17 subscriptions on that observable, so draw 17 nodes off CurrentWorkOrder. Each of them *may* also have subscriptions and so on.  It is not uncommon to have a binding re-fire many times as the tree is walked

Comment: Another thought, IE(10+) has a decent javascript profiler and it will tell you where the time is being spent.  Chrome's version is ok, but IMHO it doesn't give a good execution trace ( this called that which called something else - all with timings ).

Answer (score 0):

That last line of yours is actually just an elaborate and time-consuming way of doing

```
self.estimate().CurrentWorkOrder(workOrder);
```

Since `workOrder` was instantiated with a constructor, it will be the only object in your data that could ever compare equal to itself, so there's no need to search for it.